# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for 'maxpool1/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool')

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have implemented squeezenet model for image classification in tensorflow like this :

```
    net = conv2d(images, 96, [7, 7], stride=2, scope='conv1')
    net = max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], stride=2, scope='maxpool1')
    net = fire_module(net, 16, 64, scope='fire2')
    net = fire_module(net, 16, 64, scope='fire3')
    net = fire_module(net, 32, 128, scope='fire4')
    net = max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], stride=2, scope='maxpool4')
    net = fire_module(net, 32, 128, scope='fire5')
    net = fire_module(net, 48, 192, scope='fire6')
    net = fire_module(net, 48, 192, scope='fire7')
    net = fire_module(net, 64, 256, scope='fire8')
    net = max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], stride=2, scope='maxpool8')
    net = fire_module(net, 64, 256, scope='fire9')
    net = conv2d(net, num_classes, [1, 1], stride=1, scope='conv10')
    net = avg_pool2d(net, [13, 13], stride=1, scope='avgpool10')
    logits = tf.squeeze(net, [2], name='logits')
    return logits
```

When I run the training, I get the following error :

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for 'maxpool1/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,96,122,2].
```

I tried changing the strides and padding like how the other posts out there have suggested but nothing worked. I may be missing something simple here.

Comment: so, can we say that your code is a copy from here? https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/master/src/models/squeezenet.py

Comment: @Mehdi Structure is pretty much the same but what I'm using is not a slim version, there is no dropout layer and fully connected layer. Can you suggest how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `conv2d` is using `padding='VALID'` (no padding), perhaps you need `'SAME'` or `'same'`. Since the value is not given in the code, I just list the possible padding confusions in `conv2d` and `max_pool` defined in tensorflow. The default value of padding in these versions of `conv2d` are as follows:

- [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d), [`tf.nn.max_pool`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool) no default value
- [`tf.layers.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d), [`tf.layers.max_pool2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/max_pool2d). 
  [`tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/max_pool2d) 
  default value is `'valid'`
- [`tf.contrib.layers.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv2d) default value is `'SAME'`

Comment: Thanks. I will try to set it as same and get back with the result. Do I need to set the padding for max_pool also as 'SAME' ?

Comment: And yes, it is from tf.contrib

Comment: I haven't tested it myself but I suspect both need 'SAME'.

Comment: That is resolved but now I have different value error in squeeze layer : `ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 3 for 'logits' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,3,16,1]`

Comment: perhaps `tf.squeeze(net, [3], name='logits')` can solve it? I am not sure about the meaning of each dimension...